# how to make Jetpack compose checkbox rounded

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How do I create a rounded checkbox in Jetpackcompose like [this](https://miro.medium.com/max/300/1*Kyammh5ueefTiH1Uk15RvQ.jpeg). I tried using a Shape composable on it but it doesn't work.

Comment: this image not showing

Comment: @GaneshMB fixed it, you can check now

Answer (score 7):

We can use animations to make it behave similar to the default `Checkbox`. Using `Modifier.toggleable` on the top-level `Row` makes the entire Composable clickable, as well as creates the proper semantics for screen reader users. You can change the shape of the box to get a circular checkbox.

The row has been given a minimum height of 48dp to comply with [minimum touch target size](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7101858?hl=en).

[image]

The animation has been slowed down in this GIF to better visualize it.
[image: Rounded corner checkbox]

```
@Composable
fun RoundedCornerCheckbox(
    label: String,
    isChecked: Boolean,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    size: Float = 24f,
    checkedColor: Color = Color.Blue,
    uncheckedColor: Color = Color.White,
    onValueChange: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    val checkboxColor: Color by animateColorAsState(if (isChecked) checkedColor else uncheckedColor)
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val duration = 200

    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        modifier = modifier
            .heightIn(48.dp) // height of 48dp to comply with minimum touch target size
            .toggleable(
                value = isChecked,
                role = Role.Checkbox,
                onValueChange = onValueChange
            )
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(size.dp)
                .background(color = checkboxColor, shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                .border(width = 1.5.dp, color = checkedColor, shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = isChecked,
                enter = slideInHorizontally(animationSpec = tween(duration)) {
                    with(density) { (size * -0.5).dp.roundToPx() }
                } + expandHorizontally(
                    expandFrom = Alignment.Start,
                    animationSpec = tween(duration)
                ),
                exit = fadeOut()
            ) {
                Icon(
                    Icons.Default.Check,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    tint = uncheckedColor
                )
            }
        }
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp),
            text = label,
        )
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var checked by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
RoundedCornerCheckbox(
    label = "Checkbox label",
    isChecked = checked,
    onValueChange = { checked = it },
    modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp)
)
```

Answer (score 5):

I was looking on how to do the same thing you were asking, your question helped me on my journey so it is only fair I share. Add some animations and you are set my friend.

1. Make a round looking icon by using a box and an icon

   ```
    Box(
         modifier = Modifier
             .clip(CircleShape)
             .size(40.dp)
             .background(Color.Black)
             .padding(3.dp)
             .clip(CircleShape)
             .background(Color.White),
         contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
     ) {

       Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Check, contentDescription = "")
      }
   ```

2.Place the newly made rounded icon and some text next to each other by using a Row

```
 Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ){
    Box(
         modifier = Modifier
             .clip(CircleShape)
             .size(40.dp)
             .background(Color.Black)
             .padding(3.dp)
             .clip(CircleShape)
             .background(Color.White),
         contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
     ) {
         
       Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Check, contentDescription = "")
      }

    Text(
        text = checkedText.value,
        color = color.value,
        fontSize = 20.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 5.dp)
    )
}
```

3.Replace whatever you want with variables so you can customize
it

```
@Composable
fun RoundedCheckView(
) {

val isChecked = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val checkedText = remember { mutableStateOf("unChecked") }
val circleSize = remember { mutableStateOf(20.dp) }
val circleThickness = remember { mutableStateOf(2.dp) }
val color = remember { mutableStateOf(Color.Gray) }

Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .size(circleSize.value)
            .background(color.value)
            .padding(circleThickness.value)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(Color.White)  ,
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
       Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Check, contentDescription = "")
     }

    Text(
        text = checkedText.value,
        color = color.value,
        fontSize = 20.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 5.dp)
    )
}
```

}

4.Finally add Modifier.toggleable to the row, basically making it a clickable item that toggles (between true and false) a variable in this case isChecked. Then just customize the variables according to what you need

```
@Composable

fun RoundedCheckView() 
{
    val isChecked = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val checkedText = remember { mutableStateOf("unChecked") }
    val circleSize = remember { mutableStateOf(20.dp) }
    val circleThickness = remember { mutableStateOf(2.dp) }
    val color = remember { mutableStateOf(Color.Gray) }
Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    modifier = Modifier
        .toggleable(value = isChecked.value,role = Role.Checkbox) {
            isChecked.value = it

            if (isChecked.value) {
                checkedText.value = "Checked"
                circleSize.value = 40.dp
                circleThickness.value = 3.dp
                color.value = Color.Black
            } else {
                checkedText.value = "unChecked"
                circleSize.value = 20.dp
                circleThickness.value = 2.dp
                color.value = Color.Gray
            }
        }) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .size(circleSize.value)
            .background(color.value)
            .padding(circleThickness.value)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(Color.White)  ,
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        if(isChecked.value){
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Check, contentDescription = "")
        }
     }

    Text(
        text = checkedText.value,
        color = color.value,
        fontSize = 20.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 5.dp)
    )
}
```

}

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer, solution is simple and great.

Answer (score 4):

**This is how we can make a custom check box in jetpack compose**
**[image: 1]**

```
val isCheck = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Row {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White),
            elevation = 0.dp,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp),
            border = BorderStroke(1.5.dp, color = titleColor)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(25.dp)
                    .background(if (isCheck.value) titleColor else Color.White)
                    .clickable {
                        isCheck.value = !isCheck.value
                    },
                contentAlignment = Center
            ) {
                 if(isCheck.value)
                    Icon(Icons.Default.Check, contentDescription = "", tint = Color.White)
            }
        }

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(CenterVertically)
                .padding(start = 10.dp),
            text = "I agree with the terms & condition",
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to make it use Box with modifier content alignment center. and put an icon on there.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Check() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .size(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Red)
            .padding(5.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(Color.Blue),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Check, contentDescription = "")
    }
}
```

Comment: A Checkbox is a 3-state component, something more than a Box.

Comment: I didn't even know there was a Box composable, is there a catalog or website where one can find all the available composables ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti you can put `var state by remember { mutableStateOf(State) }` and put if on the `@Composable` to get Background color each State

Comment: @Thanoss for the catalog i read from this website https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/ but for more sample go to Github android compose sample

Comment: @RofieSagara bless this would work. thank you very much.

Comment: You can make any component a tri-state toggleable leveraging modifiers: `modifier.triStateToggleable( state: ToggleableState, enabled: Boolean, role: Role?, onClick: () -> Unit )`.  This is the way to go, the Box is the perfect building-block component for building any custom layout in compose.

Answer (score 0):

`@Composable
fun RoundedCornerCheckBox(
    isChecked: Boolean,
    tintColor: Color
) {
    val checkedState = remember { mutableStateOf(isChecked) }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(12.dp)
            .size(24.dp)
            .border(width = 3.dp, color = Color.Yellow, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(tintColor)
            .clickable { checkedState.value = !checkedState.value }
            .background(if (checkedState.value) Color.Yellow else Color.White),
    ) {
        if (checkedState.value) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Check,
                contentDescription = null,
                tint = Color.White
            )
        }
    }
}`

your code is up guys