# How to change CheckBox icons in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to change icons in the CheckBox. We were able to change it in the android using `android:button="@drawable/selector_checkbox"` but I didn't find any straightforward solution to change it in the compose.

I can change it by rewriting the Checkbox like this answer but It is not a perfect solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67363006/1105277

Is there a better way to do it in the Jetpack Compose?

Comment: There is no built in solution to change the icons because CheckBox doesn't use the different states as different icons, instead they always have the box and draw the check into it. So they don't change the icon as itself. So for now you have to use a self made solution.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a simple solution for a custom checkbox it works great for me. This is not a fit-all solution and you should modify it to fit your needs.
This uses two icons/xmls `R.drawable.checkbox_off_icon` for the frame and `R.drawable.checkbox_on_icon` for the check (wihtout the box)

```
@Composable
fun CustomCheckbox(
    modifier: Modifier,
    checked: Boolean,
    onCheckedChange: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    IconButton(modifier = modifier, onClick = { onCheckedChange(!checked) }) {
        //the box image frame unchecked
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.checkbox_off_icon),
            contentDescription = "Unchecked"
        )
        AnimatedVisibility(
            modifier = modifier,
            visible = checked,
            exit = shrinkOut(shrinkTowards = Alignment.TopStart) + fadeOut()
        ) {
            //the check only (without the surrounding box)
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.checkbox_on_icon),
                contentDescription = "Checked"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]