# How to make different-sized checkboxes in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have some checkboxes in a row, like this:

[image: 3 checkboxes size 30]

I have `modifier = Modifier.size(30.dp)`

I would like them to be bigger. Here is what happens when I set `modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp)`

[image: 3 checkboxes size 100]

It just adds annoying space instead of making them bigger. What gives? How do I get my big check boxes?

Comment: The small box [size](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Checkbox.kt?hl=ru#:~:text=private%20val-,CheckboxSize,-%3D%2020.dp)  is hardcoded and cannot be changed.  You will have to create your own checkbox if you need a different size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with the current implementation, as it is using a Hardcoded value:

[image]

You have to implement it by yourself, [check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67359701/how-to-make-jetpack-compose-checkbox-rounded).

Comment: Unfortunately I think this answers my question. Thanks! I'll work on making my own.

Comment: Oh that's a bummer...

Answer (score 6):

according to [this](https://semicolonspace.com/jetpack-compose-checkbox/) article, the `scale` modifier will do the trick

```
val scaleMultiplier = 2f //scale by 2x

Checkbox(
    modifier = Modifier.scale(scaleMultiplier)
)
```

Comment: Yes this should be accepted answer.